# Increment A Variable In AngularJS Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll preface this by saying I am very new to AngularJS so forgive me if my mindset is far off base. I am writing a very simple single page reporting app using AngularJS, the meat and potatoes is of course using the angular templating system to generate the reports themselves. I have many many reports that I am converting over from a Jinja-like syntax and I'm having a hard time replicating any kind of counter or running tabulation functionality.

Ex.

```
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for i in p %}
  {{ count }}
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

In my controller I have defined a variable like `$scope.total = 0;` which I am then able to access inside of the template without issue. What I can't quite figure out is how to increment this `total` from within an `ng-repeat` element. I would imagine this would look something like -

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="foo in bar">
        {{ foo.baz }} - {{ total = total + foo.baz }}
    </li>
</ul>
<div> {{ total }} </div>
```

This obviously doesn't work, nor does something like `{{ total + foo.baz}}`, thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Addition operator is ambiguous, but subtraction forces type conversion to Number.  `{{count - -1}}`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If all you want is a **counter** (as per your first code example), take a look at $index which contains the current (0 based) index within the containing ngRepeat. And then just display the array length for the total.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        Item number: {{$index + 1}}
    </li>
</ul>
<div>{{items.length}} Items</div>
```

If you want a **total of a particular field** in your repeated items, say price, you could do this with a filter, as follows.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        Price: {{item.price}}
    </li>
</ul>
<div>Total Price: {{items | totalPrice}}</div>
```

And the filter function:

```
app.filter("totalPrice", function() {
  return function(items) {
    var total = 0, i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) total += items[i].price;
    return total;
  }
});
```

Or, for **improved reusability**, a generic *total* filter function:

```
  app.filter("total", function() {
    return function(items, field) {
      var total = 0, i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) total += items[i][field];
      return total;
    }
  });
```

Which would be used like:

```
<div>Total price: {{items | total:'price'}}</div>
```

Comment: The second example is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks kindly.

Comment: With the generic total filter function, the field should be an argument to the returned function, not the filter itself (otherwise Angular complains that it's an unknown Provider), i.e. `app.filter("total", function() {` and `return function(items, field) {`

Answer (score 5):

I needed running total rather that plain total, so I've added upon what @TimStewart left. Here the code:

```
app.filter("runningTotal", function () {
    return function(items, field, index) {
        var total = 0, i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < index+1; i++) {
            total += items[i][field];
        }
        return total;
    };
});
```

To use it in column you just do:

```
<div>Total price: {{items | runningTotal:'price':$index}}</div>
```

Comment: Very elegant solution for running total

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but are just needing to display the total number in the object you're iterating over? Just set `$scope.total` to the length of your array (`bar` in your example above). So, `$scope.total = $scope.bar.length;`

If you're wanting the total of all the `foo.baz` properties, you just need to calculate that in your controller.

```
$scope.total = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.bar, function(foo) {
    $scope.total += foo.baz;
});
```

Comment: From a reporting angle this doesn't really make much sense. Pre-processing all of the totals in the report data before the template is processed isn't really possible in many cases.