# Getting an incrementing number in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to create a table of data. Since Angular allows you to filter and order the data in the controller, is there a way to specify an incremental value?

For example:

`Rank | UserName | Score | Last Played`

Here The ranking is going to be ordered by the highest score.

What would be the angular expression to set the Rank accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [Increment A Variable In AngularJS Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982667/increment-a-variable-in-angularjs-template)

`{{$index + 1}}`

**$index** contains the current 0-based index for `ng-repeat`

So I have:

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
  <td>{{user.Score}}</td>
  <td>{{user.LastPlayed}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```